# Shrinkwrap displacement issues

Tags: modeling, topology, displacement, shrinkwrap

I have this high poly model, and I did retopo for it.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Now I want to create a discplacement map for it, or at least to try and get some more details into the model. I added a subdivision modifier, and then a shrinkwrap modifier, and that cuased some issues in the mesh. When I added a displace modifier between the subdivision and the shrinkwrap modifier, it help but it doesn't eliminate the problem.

What can I do to fix it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: if you already have your lowpoly, why don't you simply give it a Subsurf and bake the highpoly? Why the Shrinkwrap and the Displace modifiers?

Comment: I don't know how to do what you just said.
I'm trying to create a displacement map, or use some other method to bake the extra information.

Comment: once you have the low-poly version, give it a Subdivision Surface and bake the normals, you'll find a lot of tutorials on this topic, just make sure you're in Cycles, not Eevee.

Comment: Well it seems I have a problem with baking the normal map too. I keep getting this "rainbow" effect in the normal, full of green and red and blue and pink. Changing the ray distance make no difference.

Comment: maybe share your file so that we give a try: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=oBVr4BnD" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/oBVr4BnD/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your lowpoly a *Subdivision Surface* modifier. As your highpoly goes a bit beyond the surface of your lowpoly, you need to increase the bake *Ray Distance* value up to 2m, it seems to work fine:

[image]

Comment: Do I need to apply the modifier before baking?
Also should I set it to level 1 or level 2?

Comment: do not apply the Subdivision Surface modifier of the lowpoly, unless maybe if you need to use it in another software. Give it Subdivisions: 2/2/2

Comment: [link](https://i.imgur.com/AENC0uG.png)
[link](https://i.imgur.com/gXZCDya.jpg)
In the viewport it seems like there are holes in the texture
When I try to render it seems a bit off and without all the details. Not sure if it's the normal map, or if it's just look like it because of the lighting.

Comment: If there are some artifacts, maybe paint on this part with the good color, you can do it with Blender or with an image editor, just peak a color from the normal palet and paint on the artifact part. You could also try with a cage to see if you have better result but it seems like the result you currently have is pretty good

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.
By painting, you mean like taking the normal map to photoshop and try to match the color better?
I tried to use the cage option but it didn't seem to make any difference. Not sure if I did it right.
Anyway, I tried to set the ray distance to 5m, instead of 2m, and it look like that solved the issue. [link](https://i.imgur.com/UtDeZR5.jpg)
Thanks again for the help.

Comment: yes exactly, peak a color that is around the artifact and use it to paint and remove the artifact

Comment: or you can use a clone brush if it gives a better result, in Blender you can paint with a clone brush in the 3D view